ascending step array in geometry nodes with instances decreasing every step
so, i've been trying to make a large temple structure akin to this 
using geo nodes, i need a way to stack these modules up while decreasing their number as they go up.
This is what i've managed to make while experimenting with mesh lines, it is very redundant and i really want to know if there is a way to make this easier using the repeat zone, but i haven't been able to make it work.

Here is the graph i have for this setup right now

any help is really appreciated, thank you very much!

(Using Blender 4.2.3)
Overview
A Grid mesh primitive is used to instance blocs at points selected by their row and column indices in the YZ plane. This grid is rotated around the Y axis to offset blocs in X direction. The grid size is computed from the blocs bounding box.

The GeometryNodes modifier is attached to the object to instance. This object origin is set at the center of its bottom face. For the demonstration, 5 rows and 10 columns are assumed ; the angle controlling the X offset is set to 12 degrees.
Analysis

The mesh generated by the Grid node is in the XY plane ; by a XYZ rotation of (90°, 0°, 90°), it is aligned in the YZ plane. The index $n$ of grid points is displayed in sub-figure (a). $n$ can be decomposed in a row index $i$ and a column index $j$ such that $n=i+j \times R$, with $R$ the number of rows. $i$ and $j$ indices, starting at 0, are displayed in sub-figures (b) and (c). To simplify the selection of instancing points, new indices $r$ and $c$ are computed from $i$ and $j$. Instead of bottom left corner, $r$ and $c$ origin is set at the top mid-point ; and $c$ is symmetric. $r$ and $c$ indices are displayed in sub-figures (d) and (e). Instancing points are such that $r \ge c$.

Let $H$ be the distance in "vertical" direction between two grid points (displayed as magenta bullets), $h$ the height of the object to instance, and $\alpha$ the rotation angle around Y axis controlling the offset in X direction. $H$ is computed as:
$$
H = \frac{h}{\cos{\alpha}}
$$
GeometryNodes modifier

Dark pink nodes: Computation of row indices, $i$ and $r$.
Dark green nodes: Computation of column indices, $j$ and $c$.
Dark red nodes: Offset in X direction.
Dark blue nodes: Initial rotation and translation of the grid.
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)

wow, thanks man this will take some time for me to understand but thanks for your help.

Here is another approach, I could not finish in the morning, so I'm finishing and sending now. It's nothing genial, just sort of step by step assembling. Please, pay attention to the min/max node, it helps to get instance size from sampling min max corner points of the realized instance bounding boxes. Hope it helps in some way.


And here is update with the correct top.



PS: and setup when you need an even count:

